# how can i store self.astring without clearing the data each time of the recursion?

Tags: python, recursion, tree

I have a tree code in a list style (for example '[o[p[q][r]][s]]') and I want to get the leaves of the tree. 
I use the code in my text book and try to get the leaves, however the code(that is 'def print_tree_with_prefix') is recursive so every time I run the method, it just erases the data I want. Could anyone give any idea?

Here is the code:

```
class Tree:

    def __init__(self, new_key):
        self.key = new_key
        # represent children of a node with a list
        self.children = []  
        # number of nodes in the subtree rooted at this node
        self.num_of_descendants = 0    

    # prints the tree using the specified prefix for the current line
    def print_tree_with_prefix(self, line_prefix, last_child):
        self.astring = ''#it just erases the data as the method is recursive
        count = 0

        # generate the prefix for the next line
        if len(self.children) > 0:
            next_prefix = line_prefix
            for child_index in range(len(self.children)-1):
                 self.children[child_index].print_tree_with_prefix(next_prefix, False)
            self.children[-1].print_tree_with_prefix(next_prefix, True)

        else:
            self.newkey = self.key
            self.astring = self.astring + self.key #add a new data in the string
            print(self.astring)

def load_tree(tree_str, pos = 0):
    new_node = None
    while pos < len(tree_str):
        if tree_str[pos] == "[":
            pos += 1
            new_node = Tree(tree_str[pos])
            while pos < len(tree_str) and tree_str[pos + 1] != "]":
                pos += 1
                child_tree, pos = load_tree(tree_str, pos)
                if child_tree:
                    new_node.children.append(child_tree)
                    new_node.num_of_descendants += \
                        1 + child_tree.num_of_descendants
            return new_node, pos + 1
        else:
            pos += 1
    return new_node, pos

def main():
    tree, processed_chars = load_tree('[o[p[q][r]][s]]') #the sample tree
    tree.print_tree_with_prefix("", True)

main()
```

the output is :
q
r
s
(in separate line)

expected output:
qrs 
(a whole concatenate string)

So the 'else' part of 'def print_tree_with_prefix' does not work well... Can any one help?   :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to return a single string with the concatenation of the output rather than having it printed out as-you-go?

If so then modifying your algorithm to do that is easy however this can be boiled down to a far simpler piece of code (stripping out several unused variables):

```
def print_tree_with_prefix(self):
    if not self.children:
        return self.key
    return ''.join([child.print_tree_with_prefix() for child in self.children])
```

Invoke it with:

```
def main():
    tree, processed_chars = load_tree('[o[p[q][r]][s]]')
    print tree.print_tree_with_prefix()
```

Produces:

```
qrs
```

To help you understand perhaps it is worth looking at how to fix your original algorithm with minimal changes.

I think that the key mistake you are making is thinking that there is a single `astring` variable which is being appended to by each recursive invocation.

In fact there is a separate 'astring' variable per `Tree` instance and `print_tree_with_prefix' does not return a value.  To fix this we simply change the code to return the data to the parent call:

```
# prints the tree using the specified prefix for the current line
def print_tree_with_prefix(self, line_prefix, last_child):
    astring = ''#it just erases the data as the method is recursive
    count = 0

    # generate the prefix for the next line
    if len(self.children) > 0:
        next_prefix = line_prefix
        for child_index in range(len(self.children)-1):
             astring += self.children[child_index].print_tree_with_prefix(next_prefix, False)
        astring += self.children[-1].print_tree_with_prefix(next_prefix, True)
        return astring
    else:
        self.newkey = self.key
        astring = astring + self.key #add a new data in the string
        return astring
```

And print it at the end:

```
def main():
    tree, processed_chars = load_tree('[o[p[q][r]][s]]') #the sample tree
    print tree.print_tree_with_prefix("", True)
```

After that it is just a case of simplifying the code and removing used variables.

Comment: Thank you for your help!! It works extremely well!! :)

Comment: Happy to help, please set this as the accepted answer.